# Does Visual C++ 2010 Express include an x64 compiler?

Tags: visual-c++, x86-64, visual-c++-2010-express

I have just downloaded and installed the VC++ 2010 Express tool from Microsoft.

I don't see an amd64 directory under 
**c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin**

In my old install of VC++ 2008 Express, there was an amd64 compiler, available in 
**c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe**

Does the 2010 VC++ Express include an x64 or amd64 compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can install the Platform SDK and switch the solution's SDK to Windows71 (instead of v100) to get x64 compilation working for free. The command-line compiler is only in the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I don't use the visual IDE, I just use the command-line tools. so the part about "switching the solution" won't apply to me.  I suppose I will just find the cl.exe in the appropriate amd64 subdir within c:\vc10\bin .

Comment: In that case, VC express isn't needed at all, since the platform SDK includes all of the compilers, linkers, assemblers, etc. to build a project.